# Adding few rows as per requirement in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Below is what I tried by can not get the required output,

```
d = {
'ID': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A Erik', 'B Erik', 'D', 'B Erik'],
'Month': ['20-Apr', '20-May', '20-Jun', '20-Apr', '20-Aug', '20-Apr', '20-May', '20-Aug', '20-Apr'],
'Value1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
'Value2': [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
'Value3': [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
'Value4': [40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
}

dfa = pd.DataFrame(d)

dfa = dfa.iloc[pd.to_datetime(dfa['Month'], format='%y-%b').argsort()]
dfa['Month'] = pd.Categorical(dfa['Month'], ordered=True, categories=dfa['Month'].unique())

df_pvt =    pd.pivot_table(dfa, values=['Value1','Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'],
                        index=['ID'],
                        columns=['Month'],
                        aggfunc=np.sum,
                        fill_value=None)

df_pvt = df_pvt.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
df_pvt = df_pvt.sort_index(axis=1, level='Month')
df = df_pvt.sum(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Total'], df.columns])

added = df_pvt.columns.levels[0].add_categories(['Total'])
df_pvt.columns = df_pvt.columns.set_levels(added, level=0)

df_pvt = df_pvt.join(df)

df_pvt.loc['Grand Total'] = df_pvt.sum()

added = df_pvt.columns.levels[0].add_categories(['Total of Total'])
df_pvt.columns = df_pvt.columns.set_levels(added, level=0)

df_pvt["Total of Total"] = df_pvt["Total"].sum(axis=1)
df_pvt
```

Expecting Output as shown in the red square. Trying to add following Rows in the pivot table. Grand Total By each month, Total of Erik (Including A_Erik,B_Erik) by each month, Total of D by month.

[image]

Comment: So do you need merge last 3 rows in excel? Because in pandas DataFrame this not exist for `'cels'`.

Comment: Nope, I want to create those row by pandas and merge it into a same pivot table.

Comment: So you dont need `merge` `300` to 3 columns like first value?

Comment: I wat it as I showed in the image but if it is difficult then I think it is okay if we can create a separate table

Answer (score 1):

If is also possible create separate table use:

```
#filter row and rename index
df1 = df_pvt.loc[['Grand Total']].rename({'Grand Total':'Rename by Month'})
#filter Erik if contains in index
df2 = df_pvt[df_pvt.index.str.contains('Erik')].sum().to_frame('Total of Erik per Month').T
#filter D
df3 = df_pvt.loc[['D']].rename({'D':'Total D per Month'})
#join together and aggregate sum per first level of MultiIndex in columns
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sum(level=0, axis=1).drop('Total', axis=1)
print (df)
Month                    20-Apr  20-May  20-Jun  20-Aug  Total of Total
Rename by Month           400.0   200.0   100.0   200.0           900.0
Total of Erik per Month   200.0   100.0     0.0     0.0           300.0
Total D per Month           0.0     0.0     0.0   100.0           100.0
```

Comment: Both "Grand Total" and "Grand Total By Month" both are different. Grad Total is the sum of the same column and Grand Total By Month is the sum of the month columns.

Comment: @OO7 - hmmm, problem is with real data? Because seems sample data working, can you be mpre specific? Thanks.

Comment: can we merge the table df to df_pvt?

Comment: @OO7 -  hmmm, there is problem with merge values like mentioned in comments under question. So this way is not possible in pandas. I suggest create new question for this, then some excel expert maybe create some loop solution (not 100% sure, because not easy processing)